# Advanced view animation in Android

Tags: android, animation

I'm developing an app for Android with beautiful, but hard-to-implement design with tons of custom animations. Now I need to implement animation for button, it must be dynamic glance animation that affects both button border and its text, and must move from left to right. Here is an example of such animation in iOS app.

[image: from left]

[image: to right]

So I hope you catched the main idea. I tried to use Property Animation, but it's not what I really need. Also I found many custom libraries and tried a lot of examples from SDK, but there are nothing similar.

So if you know how it can be do, answer me.

Comment: It looks like a moving gradient. Affecting a rounded cornered border and a text.

Comment: It looks like, but it's not. Because of I need gradient with mask of border and text.

Comment: Yes, right, if you want to do it via drawable resources or via Java code. But I prefer the FrameAnimation solution suggested by @GregEnnis.

Comment: @evgenii try this http://pastebin.com/VaykP9eV

Comment: looks nicely done. good job. evgenii should accept my answer since I clearly inspired people to do this the right way

Comment: @evgenii is it what you want?

Comment: @pskink it's perfect. Thanks a lot! Can you post your solution as answer? I'll accept it)

Comment: @evgenii note if you want it to use it in the Button only, you dont have a FL wrapper: yuo can extend Button class and override drawing methods as i did in FL wrapper class

Comment: Yeah! I catched it) So, what about your answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this wrapper class:

```
class FL extends FrameLayout implements ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener {
    private static final int W = 200;
    private final LinearGradient gradient;
    private final Paint paint;
    private float x;

    public FL(View child) {
        super(child.getContext());
        addView(child);
        int[] colors = {0, 0xaaffffff, 0};
        gradient = new LinearGradient(0, 0, W, 0, colors, null, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
        paint = new Paint();
        paint.setShader(gradient);
        paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP));
        x = -W;
    }

    @Override
    protected void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.saveLayer(null, null, 0);
        super.dispatchDraw(canvas);
        canvas.translate(x, 0);
        float h = getHeight();
        canvas.rotate(20, W / 2, h / 2);
        canvas.drawRect(0, -h, W, 2 * h, paint);
        canvas.restore();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
        x = (int) animation.getAnimatedValue();
        invalidate();
    }

    public void startMagic() {
        ValueAnimator a = ValueAnimator.ofInt(-W, getWidth());
        a.addUpdateListener(this);
        a.setDuration(1000).setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
        a.start();
    }
}
```

round_frame.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <corners android:radius="20dp" />
    <stroke android:color="#a00" android:width="4dp" />
</shape>
```

and test it with the following in onCreate:

```
    Button b = new Button(this);
    final FL fl = new FL(b);
    b.setTextSize(28);
    b.setTextColor(0xffaa0000);
    b.setText("click me to see the magic");
    b.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.round_frame);
    View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            fl.startMagic();
        }
    };
    b.setOnClickListener(listener);
    addContentView(fl, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

**NOTE**: if you want it to use it in the Button only, you don't have a FL wrapper: you can extend Button class and override drawing methods as i did in FL wrapper class

Answer (score 4):

I get the pre-rendered animation with a sequence of PNG files and then use the [AnimationDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimationDrawable.html) to display it.

Comment: If he needs this animation on multiple buttons of differents size/text, that would do a lot of PNG and a heavy APK !

Comment: It's not a variant, because of I need a lot of such buttons.

Comment: You can reuse the same animation for all buttons

Comment: Thank you pdegand59 for pointing out that difficult problems have challenges and trade-offs. We await your solution.

Comment: I am currently trying things out to get the expected result. The text animation was not that hard. I have trouble with the rounded corner actually ... A gif of the work in progress - http://imgur.com/jmcYRFn

Comment: @GregEnnis see my paste above ;)

Comment: Greg Ennis, i managed to animate the border to ! I had an answer to the post with implementation details and the result in GIF.

Comment: Nice... would be interesting to see how it compares with pskink implementation

Answer (score 2):

I finished my custom implementation of this.

The result so far :

[image]

This is obtained by transferring an animated gradient Shader on the static TextView
You can get the source code on the following Gist : [ShinnyTextView](https://gist.github.com/pdegand/835d3598b4b3343ba545)

The current version does not support XML customization, but you can adapt the values in the code.

If you are using this, you might want to have a more precise control on when to pause/restart the animation to avoid the ani

Comment: the big minus is that you are creating a new LinearGradient per each animation frame

Comment: Yes, translating a single gradient like you did is probably a better idea. I should change my code like this.