# ValueAnimation not animating ImageButton's margin

Tags: android

I'm applying `ValueAnimation` for an `ImageButton` and setting its bottom margin but the animation doesn't seem to be working. I've used the same function to set another view element's padding and it worked perfectly fine there.

This is my code:

```
import android.view.ViewGroup;

ImageButton locImgBtn;
ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams myLocBtnParams;
// In fragment's `onCreateView`
locImgBtn = (ImageButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.myLocationBtn);
myLocBtnParams = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) locImgBtn.getLayoutParams();

// The `ValueAnimator` function:
private void marginAnimationForLocationButton(int TO, int FROM) {  
    ValueAnimator animation = ValueAnimator.ofInt(TO, FROM);
    animation.setDuration(1100);
    animation.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
            myLocBtnParams.bottomMargin = 
            Integer.parseInt(valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue().toString());
        }
   });
animation.start();
}
```

The function would change the bottom margin of the `ImageButton` but it won't run the animation.

Comment: Call locImgBtn.requestLayout() iafter you change the margin

Comment: Where do I call this function? After `animation.start();`?

Comment: And dont call valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue().toString(), just cast getAnimatedValue() to integer type

Comment: In onAnimationUpdate()

Comment: @pskink getAnimatedValue() cannot be casted to Integer if it is not first converted into string from object. Let me try the other suggestion.

Comment: Of course it can be casted,  trust me

Comment: I got an exception when I removed .toString() from getAnimatedValue(). "The method parseInt(String) in the type Integer is not applicable for the arguments (Object)"

Comment: See onAnimationUpdate() in my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27708206/advanced-view-animation-in-android/27720228#27720228

Comment: @pskink Actually `locImgBtn.requestLayout()` fixed the problem! Thank you!

Comment: and remove that toString() workaround!

Comment: Trying out typecasting to `int` instead of using `Integer.parseInt()`